# xenserver upgrade 6.5 to 7.6 - network non-functional

Tags: xenserver

I have a small xen 6.5 (free) array (3 machines with a shared SAN) that I want to upgrade to v 7.6 (standard edition). In addition I have 2 new machines to add.

I attempted to follow instructions from [here](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/xenserver/current-release/install/upgrade.html). The installation was straightforward but following the obligatory restart the cmd UI tells me that there aren't any network interfaces available. This seems odd as the 'test network' option (by pinging various hosts) works fine. In addition, going to the command line and entering `ifconfig -a` shows all the ports.

Xen pool config - 1 mgmt interface, 3 nic in one bond and 2 nic in another bond (for iSCSI network).

What Ive tried:

- emergency network reset
  -- No change
- `xe pool-emergency-reset-master`
  -- "The server has dropped the connection"
- `xe host-list`
  -- "The server has dropped the connection"
- delete host from pool (via XenCenter) - No change
- `xe-toolstack-restart` - No change

When I installed onto the 2 new machines they found their network equipment very rapidly.

What this tells me: the network hardware (on the original upgraded box) *is* supported as the 'management interface' is working.. sort of. If I shell out from the xen UI I can ping other hosts on the network.

Not sure how to proceed.